# Camel: how to convert header to string

Tags: apache-camel

I'm setting header using `xpath()` expression. However, `xpath()` return `NodeSet`. In my case `xpath("//base/@href")` return string. I'd like to convert the result of xpath to string. How could I do it with Camel DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DSL like this, setting the resultType with String.class

```
xpath(String text, Class<?> resultType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that did the trick

```
xpath("//base/@href", String.class)
```